# jquery Datatables descending sort not working with "order" option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, datatables

I am trying to order my jQuery datatable (below), but can't get the first column to sort in descending order. I have tried `"order": [[0, 'desc']]`, but it doesn't work. [The JS fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/sxkzka4c/3/).

```
 <table id="datatable-table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th class="hidden-xs" style="width: 10%">Submission Date</
          <th class="hidden-xs" style="width: 10%">Start Date</th>
          <th class="hidden-xs" style="width: 10%">End Date</
       </tr>
     </thead>
```

Comment: You JSFiddle isn't showing anything. If you could use it in order to display some data that would be helpful and better illustrate your issue.

Comment: @annoyingmouse, sorry my bad. I've copied in the HTML part as well now.

Comment: :-) You might've done, but the link still shows the same code...

Comment: @annoyingmouse, really sorry! Look at it now (I'm reminded of an Ali G indahouse quote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your JSFiddle you want to sort the first column where you're outputting a date using the `d M Y` format so a date (UK 01/01/2017) will be represented as `01 Jan 2016`? That's not a format that DataTables understands so you'll need to add a sorting method like this:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "dateNonStandard-asc": function (a, b) {
    var x = parseInt(moment(a, "DD MMM YYYY").format("X"), 10);
    var y = parseInt(moment(b, "DD MMM YYYY").format("X"), 10);
    return (x == y) ? 0 : (x < y) ? 1 : -1;
  },
  "dateNonStandard-desc": function (a, b) {
    var x = parseInt(moment(a, "DD MMM YYYY").format("X"), 10)
    var y = parseInt(moment(b, "DD MMM YYYY").format("X"), 10);
    return (x == y) ? 0 : (x < y) ? -1 : 1;
  }
});
```

This is a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/6tzwsj59/6/) and I hope it helps.

Comment: For some reason the JSFiddle has gone, but you get the idea I hope.